# Laravel and Ajax returning 404 on request even though the url, router and controller are pointing to the same place

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

As you can see everything is properly routed, I have other functions that do something similar and are working just fine but I keep getting this errors:

> POST http://localhost:8000/apagados/4 404 (Not Found)

> DELETE http://localhost:8000/apagados/4 404 (Not Found)

```html
    //Buttons
    <button id="{{'botRestaurarProjeto'.$apagado['id']}}" value="{{$apagado['id']}}" class="botRestaurarProjeto rounded bg-blue-300 text-white p-2">Restaurar</button>
    <button id="{{'botEliminarProjeto'.$apagado['id']}}" value="{{$apagado['id']}}" class="botEliminarProjeto rounded bg-red-700 text-white p-2">Excluir</button>

<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".botRestaurarProjeto", function () {
        let id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "apagados/"+id,
            data: {
                "id": id,
            },
            success: function(result) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                // console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(testStatus);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

    //AJAX
    $(document).on("click", ".botEliminarProjeto", function () {
        let id = $(this).val();
        if(confirm("Deseja apagar definitivamente?") == true){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: "apagados/"+id,
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    _method: 'DELETE'
                },
                success: function() {
                    $("#lixo"+id).hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

```php
//ProjetoController
public function eliminar($id)
{
    $projeto = Projeto::find($id)->withTrashed();
    $projeto->forceDelete();
}

public function restaurar($id)
{
    $projeto = Projeto::find($id)->withTrashed();
    $projeto->restore();
}

//Router
Route::delete('apagados', [ProjetoController::class, 'eliminar'])->name('posts.eliminar'); 
Route::post('apagados', [ProjetoController::class, 'restaurar'])->name('posts.restaurar');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost:8000/apagados/4` is not a valid route, as you have specified:

```php
Route::delete('apagados', [ProjetoController::class, 'eliminar'])->name('posts.eliminar'); 
Route::post('apagados', [ProjetoController::class, 'restaurar'])->name('posts.restaurar');
```

So, the valid URL is `http://localhost:8000/apagados`. If you want that to work as expected, you have to change your routes to:

```php
Route::delete('apagados/{id}', [ProjetoController::class, 'eliminar'])->name('posts.eliminar'); 
Route::post('apagados/{id}', [ProjetoController::class, 'restaurar'])->name('posts.restaurar');
```

Read more about [`Route`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer but now I got this:
DELETE http://localhost:8000/apagados/4 500 (Internal Server Error)
POST http://localhost:8000/apagados/6 500 (Internal Server Error)

Even though the CSRF token is properly configured

Comment: So, my answer is working, mark this answer as correct, and create a new question, because your real problem was you could not use this URL as expected. 500 is not related to this change, but rather is in your controller. Create that new question showing the controller and all stuff and we will help you ! (I know you are sharing your controller here, and I see no error, just show it again and add more info, try using `dd` helper inside your controller or see Laravel's logs)